# Change Serialised JSON output

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

In my Django project I have a django rest framework serialiser

`class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):`

that takes a filtered query set and then serialises it.

I then use `JSONRenderer().render( testserializer.data )`
to convert it to JSON

The issue I face is that I need to change the output, currently I get this:

```
b'[{"car_age":"1","car_type":"1"},{"car_age":"4","car_type":"2"}]'
```

But I want the return response in the views to have this json payload:

```
{“cars”:[{"car_age":"1","car_type":"1"},{"car_age":"4","car_type":"2"}]}
```

Any help in achieving this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update your view, return this:

```
return JSONRenderer().render({'cars':testserializer.data})
```

instead of

```
return JSONRenderer().render(testserializer.data)
```

Also instead of rendering response each time manually, it's a common practice to use `Response` class:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
return Response({'cars':testserializer.data})
```

This will use renderer specified in [`DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#setting-the-renderers) setting.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, exactly what I wanted to know, thanks again.